# Differenciate between onMarkerClick and onClusterItemClick event in Android

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I am using google map v2 with 1000 plus markers being fetched from web service. So for this reason i am using map clustering. I am showing info window `onMarkerClick` but the problem is that when the user click on cluster it shows info window because `onMarkerClick` event is triggered. I want to zoom further when cluster of markers is clicked. There is `onClusterItemClick` event but its not working with `onMarkerClick`. Any feasible solution is appreciated in advance.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer of this issue. Actually you can use the following two listeners on `ClusterManager` object say `mClusterManager` according to your requirement :

```
1- setOnClusterClickListener

2- setOnClusterItemClickListener
```

but before that you have to set this:

```
map.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);
```

Comment: What's different between `setOnClusterClickListener` and `setOnClusterItemClickListener`?

Comment: setOnClusterClickListener will trigger if clicked on a group of markers represented with single cluster icon. setOnClusterItemClickListener will trigger if any particular marker in the cluster is pressed

Answer (score -1):

I think you can check the current zoom level, and preform your normal `onMarkerClick` items only if the current zoom level is less than a number, or you make some kind of flag that remember if the current item is clustered.

Comment: This doesn't work because there could be non clustered markers also on the Map.